My tickets has JFK to Miami and then Guyana
My ticket has JFK to Miami then Miami to Guyana, but I am booking a separate ticket to Miami.
I want to know if my first ticket can still be used to go to Guyana.

Are you saying "if I don't take the first leg of my two leg trip, can I still take the second?"

This question is similar to: Consequences of not showing up for one leg of journey. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What airline(s)? What is the fare code? Rules vary a lot.

Usually not.
If you miss a leg on a ticket the airline usually cancels the further flights on that ticket.
That is because tickets with a short leg as well as a long leg are often cheaper than the longer leg by itself or the whole distance in one go.
Best contact the airline as soon as possible to see if you can change the ticket you have now to the one you need, maybe by moving the first flight to when you want to travel that leg.
